TP-Link omada ER706W gigabit VPN router configuration
I want to replace the router I bought with the router given by my service provider. The router my service provider gave me was specially produced and its name is TP-Link Archer C5v. The router I bought is TP-Link omada ER706W gigabit VPN router.
Settings of the router provided by my service provider:
WAN table
WAN table
WAN configuration
The settings of TP-Link omada ER706W gigabit VPN router are:
WAN configuration
TP-Link omada ER706W gigabit VPN router seems to have established a connection and received an IP, but there is no internet. After a while, the web page opens and tells me that the username and password are incorrect. Likewise, my service provider's customer service said that you could not get an IP because your username and password were incorrect.
I know the username and password are correct. I made the MAC address of the WAN port of the TP-Link omada ER706W gigabit VPN router the same as that of the WAN port of the TP-Link Archer C5v router.
MAC Configuration
I could not enable Nat  and other WAN settings that say connected on the WAN page of the TP-Link Archer C5v router. Other than that, there's nothing I can see.
WAN table
WAN Configuration
Here is a simulation of the modem interface page.
Can you help me get internet connection? Thank you to everyone who read and replied.

First, I think the first sentence of your question is not correct. Second, are you sure about the password? The router may be showing some characters there as a placeholder, or otherwise be keeping the password to itself. How did you get the password? If you want your own router to be your only router, ask your ISP for PPPoE login details. If they refuse to give them to you, you could always chain the routers (put yours behind the ISP's. That would be functionally equivalent for your LAN, it would give you almost no latency penaly, and, with spoofed TTL, it's almost undetectable to ISP.
